# What youth organizations are there that are active in Esperanto?

Tags: movado

I've been a part of the board of [TEJO](https://www.tejo.org/) during the last year, the umbrella organization that connects the worldwide Esperanto youth movement. 
That doesn't mean that is the only organization active in Esperanto, and each national organization has their own organizational structure.

Even though I've been in Esperantujo for a while, I still come across organizations and activists that I didn't know about before, like [SAT](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennacieca_Asocio_Tutmonda). Even though I know about the biggest youth organization, maybe there are others that I have missed.

Comment: Is the body of this "question" supposed to already answer the question in the title of this "question"? If yes, please post it as an answer instead. (It's OK to answer your own questions.) If no, please repeat (or paraphrase) the actual question in the "question" body, so that it's clear what is being asked.

Comment: Hm, I'll try to clarify. I've been in Esperantujo for a few years now, but it took me a logn time until I learnt about for example SAT, https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sennacieca_Asocio_Tutmonda . So I'm wondering how many other organizations out there that I have missed.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your question, TEJO is an umbrella organisation that connects with national youth organisations. Because of that they have [a nice list of national youth organisations](https://www.tejo.org/pri-ni/strukturo/landaj-sekcioj/) on their website which can be used as a starting point.

Some examples from that list that I know to be active are:

- [Junulara Esperantista Franca Organizo (JEFO)](http://esperanto-jeunes.org/) – French youth

They produce a nice calendar every year.

- [Dana Esperanta Junulara Organizo (DEJO)](http://dejo.dk/) – Danish youth

They recently helped create an [Esperanto word game app](https://www.liberafolio.org/2019/08/02/vortludo-vortludo-ne-permesas-miauindon/).

- [Junularo Esperantista Brita (JEB)](http://jeb.org.uk/) – British youth

They organise a large event in the UK roughly once a year and often have smaller less formal events as well.